# Android Firebase storing users in database who have clicked on a button

Tags: android, firebase

For our class we are making an app that lists bars within a certain radius of a user's location and each bar will show what users have responded YES to attending said bar.  So basically we are stuck on the way to store the user who has clicked on a button YES for a certain bar in our database.  Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

if you ask for schema this is an example

`-Bars
   -BarID 
      -name
      -location
      -Attendees 
         -uid1 
         -uid2
 -Users
   -Uid1`